# Nougat 7.0: I cant explore phone memory in my computer

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I formatted my sd card as internal storage but when I connect to computer via USB its shows memory card storage space only! How to explore mobile internal memory?

(Using Android Nougat)

Answer (score 0):

To see your Internal Storage, on Android Nougat 7.0 and above, open the notification tray on your device, tap on the persistent notification "USB charging this device" and select "Transfer files".

[image: Via The Android Soul]

Source: http://www.theandroidsoul.com/set-transfer-files-mtp-default-nougat/